# In aem 6.0 Error: Title and Description Missing for path /content/musicschool

Tags: aem

I am trying to activate a page in Site Admin using AEM 6.0. I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error: Title and Description Missing for path /content/.
```

I'm not using a scheduler. I've included the error from the logs:

```
04.06.2016 18:05:44.759 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1465043744500] POST /bin/replicate.json HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.replication.impl.servlets.CommandServlet Error during replication: Title and Description Missing
com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationException: Title and Description Missing at com.adobe.eventhandler.PreprocessorExample.preprocess(com.adobe.eventhandler.PreprocessorExample.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this class "**com.adobe.eventhandler.PreprocessorExample.java**" is written by you or AEM vender ?

It seems that this class processes the validation when the page is activating.

Comment: hi, am not used any preprocessors also. But also am getting the issue. @Ha Doan